# Unix file Sort rows on the basis of timestamp column

Tags: linux, shell, unix, unix-timestamp

Unix file Sort rows on the basis of timestamp column

```
A 00:00:01
K 01:02:00
C 01:02:03
N 01:03:02
```

Excepted output should be sort basis on last column HH:MM:SS

```
N 01:03:02
C 01:02:03
K 01:02:00
A 00:00:01
```

I tried command sort -k 4  -t " " -n -r txt. But this not giving expected result.

Comment: Have you done any research or made any attempt to solve the issue yourself first? If so, please show your attempt and explain what problems you have.

Comment: I tried command sort -k 4  -t " " -n -r txt. But this not giving expected result.

Comment: `this not giving expected result.` What result does it give? Why `-k4`? There are only two columns?

Comment: in my original file column number forth. Your below solution worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
sort -k 2 -r txt
```

should be enough